# Accessing structure elements using iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator, operators

I have defined this structure and vector:

```
struct All
{
    string name;
    int id;
};
vector<All*> all;
```

I'm inserting created structure with data to the vector using lower_bound function to keep it sorted.

```
All * tmp = new All(name, id);
auto it = lower_bound(all.begin(), all.end(), name, compare2());
all.insert(it, tmp);
```

When I want to find the structure with `name = test` I do this :

```
auto it1 = lower_bound(all.begin(), all.end(), name, compare2());
```

It gives me iterator `it` to that structure with name containing test in it but why can't I access the elements of the structure like this `cout << it1 -> id;`? How can I access elements of that structure?

Comment: must you store pointers to All in the vector? It makes life hard for you and everyone else. Store `All` objects.

Comment: What does it mean that you cannot access? Do you get compile error or runtime error? Also, it's strange a bit that you find lower bound of `name`, not `tmp` in your second piece of code. Theoretically it could work but I'm not sure that it's obvious.

Comment: I was getting errors but `*it -> id` solved it i did not realize that i store pointers in that vector so it's pointer to pointer

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following way

```
cout << ( *it ) -> id;
```

Expression `*it` gives the element in the vector that is a pointer.

Comment: Could you give me please some explanation why it's dereferenced before accesing that element?

Answer (score 2):

You have to dereference your iterator a second time, in order to access the fields of the datastructure:

```
(*it1)->id;
```

---

**Explanation:**

Conceptually, iterators are little more than pointers to an element in the container (in fact, most implementations of `std::vector<T>::iterator` are pointers to `T`). In your case, the container element is a pointer itself, so you have to dereference the iterator two times: The first (`*it`) gives you a reference to the pointer stored in the container which is then dereferenced by the `->` operator to give access to the actual object field.

The way you wrote it you where trying to access a member of the iterator (which doesn't have any if it is implemented as a raw pointer)